# Java Spring Web Application starts slowly in debug mode

Tags: java, spring, debugging, tomcat, jersey

i have a java web application, using Spring, Jersey (jax-rs) and Hibernate.

It runs fine and fast, but there are some days it takes a big amount of time to initialize in debug mode only and when it starts is really slow...

I'm using Eclipse 3.6, Apache Tomcat 6 and java 1.6.0_29 for MAC OS X.

Application begin to log slow after writing this log line:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

and before this log lines:

```
30-dic-2011 10.51.25 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
    com.example.project.web.rest
```

How can I investigate? Any suggestions?

Unfortunately I really don't know what I did to reduce performance..

Thanks a lot for help!
Davide.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

One thing that's helped me in a similar situation is to delete all breakpoints in Eclipse. It's worth a try.

Comment: Unbelieveable... but it *does* work! :) Actually there is no need to delete the breakpoints, using the "skip all breakpoints" option is enough

Comment: Worked for Idea. And now I wonder - why the hell it worked since there was no breaks communicated!

Comment: Had same issue even not in debug mode in Idea. Removing breakpoints helped.

Comment: thanks @AJPerez good one. I wouldn't want to delete the break points.

Comment: While the answer provides a relief, I would be interested to see an answer how to keep breakpoints, but have normal performance. After all we don't add breakpoints for the sport.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. To view and delete all breakpoints see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837403/how-to-view-all-the-breakpoints-in-eclipse

Comment: Same worked in intelliJ too. Just skipped the endpoints and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Thank God I found this thread... I lost a whole day from cleaning my workspace, running a JVM profiler, clearing my .m2 folder, burning sage, throwing salt over my shoulder and screaming bloody Mary in a dark bathroom 13 times.

Comment: @ItGrunt next time, try drinking those bloody Maries instead of screaming them :-)

Answer (score 3):

Method entry-exit breakpoints or conditional breakpoints usually cause this issue. Removing those breakpoints would resolve the issue. It worked for me.

Comment: extremely useful mate.

Comment: preferably get rid of such breakpoints as soon as you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

following steps can improve performance

- Clean Tomcat Work Directory
- Add/remove application from server>tomcat

I did improved a lot, speeds up debugging process.