# How to view all the breakpoints in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I am new to eclipse and I am unable to view all the breakpoints that I have placed. I even tried Window --> Show View --> Breakpoints but that is also not working.

Comment: For me Window-> Show View -> Breakpoints show all breakpoints. Did you set breakpoint?

Comment: Yes I did set the breakpoints and they also appear when I debug the application but I am unable to remove them now.

Comment: Just select Breakpoint in Breakpoints View and press del button, or find string and "Toggle Breakpoint"

Answer (score 106, accepted):

As other users have suggested, to view all breakpoints : Window-> Show View -> Breakpoints.

To delete them, there are three ways:

1. select the breakpoint & click on the cross button displayed in the same view.
2. select the breakpoint, right click & select remove. (You can also temporarily disable it & remove all the breakpoints from this menu.)
3. Go to the breakpoint in your file & double-click it.

Answer (score 37):

Here is what worked for me, just today, Run-> Remove All Breakpoints

Answer (score 5):

On the top-right corner, there is a search bar(Quick Access). 
You can search for breakpoints there and select breakpoints from options. 
All the breakpoints will be listed down.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove all breakpoints by following below steps. Go to

> Run -> Remove All Breakpoints.

This will remove all breakpoints.

Comment: The question is about how to view all breakpoints, not to remove all breakpoints

Comment: Thank you for notifying me. I misread as 'remove' break points.

Answer (score 2):

For Oxygen.3a I use:

- Window > Perspective > Open perspective > debug, and it shows the breakpoints window by default.
- Then ALT + SHIFT + Q, B toggles the window (or Window > Show view > Breakpoints)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Windows->Show View->(Others)->(Debug)->Breakpoints->unchecked all debug points

and unchecked all debug points which you have checked, start in debug mode again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: Press Alt + Shift + Q, B

Answer (score 0):

On Bottom there are many tabs like console ,Development Mode etc like wise 
Break Point also there you find all toggle break points.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Debug icon and click Reset. I hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

This shows all the breakpoints in the project.

Window > Perspective > Open perspective > debug, and it shows the breakpoints window by default.

Answer (score -3):

Go to **Run > Remove All Breakpoints**

Comment: Wouldn’t this remove the break points? Original author is asking how to view (not remove)